# Can we prove that $t^\frac{1}{t}>y^\frac{1}{y}$ without analyzing function $x^\frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms, exponentiation

> Is it possible to prove that 
>   $$t^\frac{1}{t}>y^\frac{1}{y}$$ knowing that $e\leq{t} <y$ and without looking at the function $$x^\frac{1}{x}$$?

I already tried with exponentials, logs, properties of logs, but nothing seems to work. In fact, the above writing is another form for saying $t^y>y^t$, which seems impossible to solve with standard methods. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: In fact, the function $f(x)=x^{1\over x}$ increases ($f'(x)\ge 0$) for $x\in [1,e]$. When we take the values for $t$ and $y$ on that interval, the inequality does not hold. (I wanted to check whether it is true or not so i tried to analyze the function a little bit.)

Comment: You are right @Vanwij. Thanks very much for pointing that out!

Comment: You could go with $t^{\frac{1}{t}} = e^{\frac{1}{t}\ln t}$, and analyse $\frac{1}{t}\ln t$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show that
it is true for
$t \ge e$,
but you have to look at
the function or its log.

As Vanwij suggested,
let $f(x) = x^{1/x}$,
though it is easier
with its log
$g(x) = \dfrac{\ln(x)}{x}
$.

Then
$g'(x)
=\dfrac{1-\ln(x)}{x^2}
$
so
$g'(x) = 0$
for $x = e$
and
$g'(x) < 0$
for $x > e$.

Therefore
if $e \le t \lt y$
then
$g(t) > g(y)
$.

However,
you can show that
$x^{1/x}$
has its max just from
$e^x \gt 1+x$
except at $x = 0$.

(This is not original.)

If $x \ne e$
we have
$e^{\frac{x-e}{e}}
\gt 1+\frac{x-e}{e}
=1+\frac{x}{e}-1
=\frac{x}{e}
$
so
$e^{\frac{x}{e}-1}
\gt \frac{x}{e}
$
or
$e^{\frac{x}{e}}
\gt x
$
or
$e^{1/e} > x^{1/x}$.

Comment: But the question explicitly asks not to analyze the function $f$ in question, doesn't it?

Comment: I know. I added some stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid and useful answer!!

Comment: @martycohen How do we know that if $x \ne e$
we have
$e^{\frac{x-e}{e}}
\gt 1+\frac{x-e}{e}$?

Comment: Because $e^z > 1+z$ for any $z \ne 0$. You have to assume something.

Comment: I see, thanks again!